# Function in then is being called before when ends

Tags: javascript, jquery, .when

I can't figure out why JQuery doesn't wait until one function ends. I'm using `when().then()` clausule and the first function returns `AJAX` call.

```
$('#id_language_from').on('change', function () {
        blockLoader();
        var rtl = refreshTargetLanguages();
        var rstl = refreshSummaryTargetLanguages();
        $.when(rtl).then(rstl).then(unblockLoader);

    });
```

The problem is that `rstl` has to wait until `rtl` ends but it doesn't.

**CHROME CONSOLE:** (RSTL should be after DONE SUCCESS RTL)

```
RTL
RSTL
...
DONE SUCCESS RTL
```

**RTL and RSTL**

```
function refreshTargetLanguages() {
    console.log('RTL');
    var language_id = $('#id_language_from').val();
    if (language_id != '') {
        var request_url = '/orders/ajax/get-languages-to-exclude/';
        return $.ajax({
            url: request_url,
            method: 'post',
            data: {'language_id': language_id},
            success: function (data) {
                $('.class_target_languages').show();

                window.changeunbind = 1;

                $('.target_language_choice.active').trigger('click');

                window.changeunbind = 0;

                $.each(data, function (key, value) {
                    hideTargetLanguageById(key);
                });
                console.log('DONE SUCCESS RTL')
            }
        })
    } else {
        console.log('call HATL');
        return hideAllTargetLanguages();
    }
}

function refreshSummaryTargetLanguages() {
    console.log('RSTL');
    var summ_ul_targ_langs = $('#summary_target_languages > ul');
    $('#id_summary_price').text('');
    var active_languages = $('.target_language_choice.active');
    console.log(active_languages);
    var words_count = $('#id_word_count').text();
    if (active_languages.length < 1 || !Boolean(words_count)) {
        console.log('emtpy');
        return summ_ul_targ_langs.find('ul').empty();

    }
    blockLoader();
    var active_languages_ids = [];
    active_languages.each(function () {
        active_languages_ids.push($(this).attr('data-pk'));
    });
    var source_language_id = $('#id_language_from').val();

    var summ_ul_targ_langs = $('#summary_target_languages > ul');
    summ_ul_targ_langs.empty();
    if ((words_count == '') || (words_count == 'NA')) {
        return
    }
    return $.post('/orders/languages-prices/', {
        'word_count': words_count,
        'language_from_id': source_language_id,
        'languages_to_ids': active_languages_ids
    }).done(function (response) {
        var estimated_price = response['estimated_price'];
        var items = response['items'];
        $.each(items, function (_, item) {
            var name = item['name'];
            var id = item['id'];
            var price = item['price'];
            var price_per_word = item['price_per_word'];
            summ_ul_targ_langs.append('<li>' + name + ': ' + price_per_word + ' x ' + words_count + ' = ' + price + '</li>');
        });
        $('#id_summary_price').text(estimated_price + ' €');
        console.log('DONE RSTL')


    });

}
```

Do you know where is the problem?

**EDIT**

According to Anthonys answer, I've changed RTL to:

```
function refreshTargetLanguages() {
    console.log('RTL');
    var language_id = $('#id_language_from').val();
    var deferred = $.Deferred();
    if (language_id != '') {
        var request_url = '/orders/ajax/get-languages-to-exclude/';
        $.ajax({
            url: request_url,
            method: 'post',
            data: {'language_id': language_id}
        }).then(function(data){
            $('.class_target_languages').show();

            window.changeunbind = 1;

            $('.target_language_choice.active').trigger('click');

            window.changeunbind = 0;

            $.each(data, function (key, value) {
                hideTargetLanguageById(key);
            });
            console.log('DONE SUCCESS RTL');
            deferred.resolve();
        }, function(error){
            deferred.reject(error);
        });
    } else {
        console.log('call HATL');
        hideAllTargetLanguages();
        deferred.resolve();
    }
    return deferred.promise();
}
```

Which did not helped too...

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass the function to the `then()`, but you are executing the function before the `ajax`

`var rstl = refreshSummaryTargetLanguages()`

should be

`var rstl = refreshSummaryTargetLanguages`

or you can put everything into one line
`refreshTargetLanguages().then(refreshSummaryTargetLanguages).then(unblockLoader);`

May not be related to the problem, I would also modify the `refreshTargetLanguages` a little bit so it returns a promise that doesn't get resolved until `console.log('DONE SUCCESS RTL')` is logged

```
function refreshTargetLanguages() {
    console.log('RTL');
    var language_id = $('#id_language_from').val();
    var deferred = $.Deferred();
    if (language_id != '') {
        var request_url = '/orders/ajax/get-languages-to-exclude/';
        $.ajax({
            url: request_url,
            method: 'post',
            data: {'language_id': language_id}
        }).then(function(data){
            $('.class_target_languages').show();

            window.changeunbind = 1;

            $('.target_language_choice.active').trigger('click');

            window.changeunbind = 0;

            $.each(data, function (key, value) {
                hideTargetLanguageById(key);
            });
            console.log('DONE SUCCESS RTL');
            deferred.resolve();
        }, function(error){
            deferred.reject(error);
        });
    } else {
        console.log('call HATL');
        hideAllTargetLanguages();
        deferred.resolve();
    }
    return deferred.promise();
}
```

Comment: Thanks but this didn't helped too. I've replaced the function and console logs the same way. (added screenshot at the bottom of the question)

Comment: Your `var rstl = refreshSummaryTargetLanguages()` should be `var rstl = refreshSummaryTargetLanguages`. You'd want to pass the function to the `then`, but not calling the function

Comment: I've changed it to var rtl = refreshTargetLanguages;
        var rstl = refreshSummaryTargetLanguages;
        $.when(rtl).then(rstl).then(unblockLoader); And now, only rstl is being executed... I really don't understand why. On the other hand, when I try to do this: $.when(rtl()).then(rstl())... it is the same as before, rstl is called before end of rtl

Comment: you don't have to change `var rtl...`, changing just the line of `var rstl...` should be good enough

Comment: Alternatively, you can put everything into one line `refreshTargetLanguages().then(refreshSummaryTargetLanguages).then(unblockLoader)`, I think it gives a clearer picture in one line.